# Word puzzle algorithm

Tags: algorithm

There is a word puzzle game available for mobile phones, at least for Android.

You are given a N x N matrix of letters, for example 3 x 3. You need to join the adjacent letters to find a meaningful word.

The app shuffles amazing count of meaningful words randomically into one gameplay.

Given a list of words, what can be the algorithm to produce this matrix? Any idea?

See picture of one finished gameplay. "nyár" means summer. On the left you can see the list of words the player should have guessed, the matrix is on the mid-right.

[image: evaluation of scores]

Comment: There are many ways to do this. One easy way would be trial-and-error: having the frequency of each letter in your language, take 9 weighted-random letters. Then check your dictionary and see how many words can be created, if they are more than N, finish; if not, repeat.

Comment: You can try searching for "Dense Boggle Board" generation algorithms. Here is one site that uses simulated annealing: http://www.gtoal.com/scrabble/chuong_do/boggle.html